# Unpack an array filled with lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I started with something like this:

```
[a,b,s,d]
[k,e,f,s,d]
[o,w,g]
```

Then I wanted to rearrange them by length in descending order so that I get this:

```
[k,e,f,s,d]
[a,b,s,d]
[o,w,g]
```

However, to do that, I appended each of those into an array as such:

```
arr = [[a,b,s,d], [k,e,f,s,d], [o,w,g]]
```

so that I could just use:

```
sorted(arr, key=len).reverse()
```

But now I can't unpack arr to just get:

```
[k,e,f,s,d]
[a,b,s,d]
[o,w,g]
```

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What were they contained in originally?

Comment: `sorted(arr, key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: @Ffisegydd They were originally in a txt file then I put each in an array

Comment: Your lists were originally in a txt file? (They're lists, not arrays, arrays are completely different things in Python so please don't confuse them). And you want them back in a text file but in the correct order?

Comment: falsetru gave you the answer

Comment: No. Don't want them back in the text file. Just want them to be back in list form, so not inside that arr. I want to look at leach line's character individually. @Ffisegydd

Comment: Then look at `arr[0]` then `arr[1]` and so on...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm not asking how to reverse. I'm asking how to unpack

Comment: @StudentJ, Do you mean something like this? `a, b, c = arr`

Comment: @StudentJ, `a,b,c = arr` does exactly that

Answer (score 0):

`reverse()` is an in-place function:

```
arr = [['a','b','s','d'], ['k','e','f','s','d'], ['o','w','g']] 
a = sorted(arr, key=len)
print a
# [['o', 'w', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 's', 'd'], ['k', 'e', 'f', 's', 'd']]
print a.reverse()
# None
print a
# [['k', 'e', 'f', 's', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 's', 'd'], ['o', 'w', 'g']]
```

`reverse()` has no output, but it does reverse the array.